# S3 Object Expiration using boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I was trying to figure out a way to clean up my s3 bucket. I want to delete all the keys that are older than X days ( In my case X is 30 days).

I couldn't figure out a way to delete the objects in s3.

I used the following approaches, none of which worked (By worked, I mean I tried getting the  object after X days, and s3 was still serving the object. I was expecting "Object not found" or "Object expired" message

Approach 1:

```
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = my_key_name
    expires = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=(10))
    expires = expires.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
    k.set_contents_from_filename(filename,headers={'Expires':expires})
```

Approach 2:

```
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = "Event_" + str(key_name) + "_report"
    expires = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=(10))
    expires = expires.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
    k.set_meta_data('Expires', expires)
    k.set_contents_from_filename(filename)
```

If anyone can share the code that was working for them, which deletes s3 objects, that would be really great

Answer (score 17):

You can use [lifecycle policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html#intro-lifecycle-rules) to delete objects from s3 that
are older than X days.  For example, suppose you have these
objects:

```
logs/first
logs/second
logs/third
otherfile.txt
```

To expire everything under logs/ after 30 days, you'd say:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.lifecycle import (
    Lifecycle,
    Expiration,
)

lifecycle = Lifecycle()
lifecycle.add_rule(
    'rulename',
     prefix='logs/',
     status='Enabled',
     expiration=Expiration(days=30)
)

s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket('boto-lifecycle-test')
bucket.configure_lifecycle(lifecycle)
```

You can also retrieve the lifecycle configuration:

```
>>> config = bucket.get_lifecycle_config()
>>> print(config[0])
<Rule: ruleid>
>>> print(config[0].prefix)
logs/
>>> print(config[0].expiration)
<Expiration: in: 30 days>
```

Comment: I was trying to test this, and wondering if expiration can be tested by using minutes/seconds.

Looks like days=1 is the minimum time that can be used

Comment: No way to use minutes/seconds. The minimum is 0 days and the only guarantee is that AWS it take action before next day midnight UTC as per [PUT Bucket lifecycle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlifecycle.html).

Comment: Please change LifeCycle to Lifecycle in "from boto.s3.lifecycle import LifeCycle" as Lifecycle is the right class name.

Comment: Any way to test if an object is under a particular lifecycle?

Comment: item = s3.Object(bucket, key)
item.expiration
This will display when it expires and what rule-id it is governed by

Answer (score 7):

The answer by *jamesis* is using `boto` which is an older version and will be deprecated. 
The current supported version is `boto3`.

The same expiration policy on the logs folder can be done as follows:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

client = boto3.client('s3')
try:
    policy_status = client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
               Bucket='boto-lifecycle-test',
               LifecycleConfiguration={
                    'Rules': 
                           [
                             {
                             'Expiration':
                                {
                                 'Days': 30,
                                 'ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker': True
                                },
                             'Prefix': 'logs/',
                             'Filter': {
                               'Prefix': 'logs/',
                             },
                             'Status': 'Enabled',
                            }
                        ]})
except ClientError as e:
     print("Unable to apply bucket policy. \nReason:{0}".format(e))
```

**This will override any existing lifecycle configuration policy on `logs`.**

A good thing to do would be to check if the bucket exists and if you have the permissions to access it before applying the expiration configuration i.e. before the `try-except`

```
bucket_exists = client.head_bucket(
   Bucket='boto-lifecycle-test'
)
```

Since the `logs` folder itself isn't a bucket but rather an object within the bucket `boto-lifecycletest`, the bucket itself can have a different expiration policy.
You can check this from the result in `policy_exists` as below.

```
policy_exists = client.get_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
    Bucket='boto-lifecycle-test')
bucket_policy = policy_exists['Rules'][0]['Expiration']
```

More information about setting the expiration policy can be checked at [Expiry policy](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration)

Comment: I'm using this with Ceph, and I had to comment out the `'ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker': True` line, otherwise I'd get a Malformed XML error.

Comment: Yes maybe the flag has been deprecated

Answer (score 1):

The above python script by *Vaulstein* throws a Malformed XML exception. Please remove extra "*,*" at the end of line "*'Status': 'Enabled',*".

Comment: You should simply submit an edit request for the answer from @Vaulstein or add this as a comment. This shouldn't be posted as an answer. I would recommending submitting an edit

Comment: Throws an error 'Edits must be at least 6 characters' on submitting edit request. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Then adding it as a comment to the answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: @mbbce He'd probably wanted to but then he must have at least 20(?) reputation to do that. I've run into that infinite loop, you know.

Answer (score 1):

```html
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='my-aws-login-profile', region_name='ap-south-1')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket_lifecycle_configuration = s3.BucketLifecycleConfiguration('my-s3bucket')
    try:
        bucket_lifecycle_configuration.put(
            LifecycleConfiguration={
                'Rules': [
                    {
                        'Expiration': {
                            'Days': 7
                        },
                        'ID': 'life cycle config for log folder',
                        'Filter': {
                            'Prefix': 'logs/',
                        },
                        'Status': 'Enabled',
                        'NoncurrentVersionExpiration': {
                            'NoncurrentDays': 7
                        },
                        'AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload': {
                            'DaysAfterInitiation': 7
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print e.message
        exit(1)
```

Parsed XML Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LifecycleConfiguration>
   <Rule>
      <ID>life cycle config for log folder</ID>
      <Filter>
         <Prefix>logs/</Prefix>
      </Filter>
      <Status>Enabled</Status>
      <Expiration>
         <Days>7</Days>
      </Expiration>
      <NoncurrentVersionExpiration>
         <NoncurrentDays>7</NoncurrentDays>
      </NoncurrentVersionExpiration>
      <AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload>
         <DaysAfterInitiation>7</DaysAfterInitiation>
      </AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload>
   </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```